# Connecting Database to Application with NameCheap

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to connect a database to my application I'm designing (Android in Android Studio) and I keep running into errors. I'm designing a login page, so putting the database in the resource folder isn't an option.

I followed a tutorial that used 000webhost, so I tried that. My PHP code always delivers a 'not connected message'. I also tried setting up a database via NameCheap on my hosting and connecting via that, but my PHP code gives the same error. In hopes that it's just an error I've made, I'm going to paste the PHP code here (the app code is irrelevant, the PHP is directly giving me an error).

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ID HERE", "PASSHERE", "DBNAMEHERE");
    if (!$conn){
        echo "Not Connected :(";
    } else{
        echo "Connection Established! :)";
    }
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $company = $_POST["company_id"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];


    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, password, email, company_id, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $password, $email, $companyid, $phone);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Obviously with the values up top entered, just clearing them for security sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `$con` and `$conn`.
If it doesn't works, make sure you doesn't have active VPN.